# Move android studio project to an already created Github Repository

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control

I made an android studio project and I also have an empty Github repository already created where I am a contributor. How do I move my android studio project to this already created repository?
I tried but I am not able to achieve this.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is not to bring your project into an existing git repository, but to bring git to your project.

At the root of your project:

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add origin <url>`, where `<url>` is your GitHub repository's URL.
3. `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` to setup your default branch and remote.

Comment: Yes. I did it in the same way. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Instead of moving the project using android studio to an existing Github repository, I did it locally using the command line. The steps I followed are [here](http://www.yudiz.com/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/). Now its perfect and further commits can be now done directly from the android studio.